# Eloquent relationship. Changed table name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have users table with id on it. 
My project model has $fillable fields:

```
  protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'description',
    'visibility_level',
    'creator_id'
  ];
```

relationship:

```
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
```

In Users model relationship:

```
  public function projects()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
  }
```

Now creator_id is refering to user_id. I have set up my project model table with:

```
  $table->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

But then I try to store data, it still tried to add user_id:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'
```

My store() method:

```
public function store(ProjectRequest $request)
{

$project = new Project($request->all());

Auth::user()->projects()->save($project);

flash()->success('Project have been created');

return redirect('news/');
}
```

Am I searching In wrong place or what? I dont understand why its "user_id" where is this "user_id" generated name comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user_id` key  comes from the name of your class (`User`). All laravel does is snake case it and append `_id` to it. To fix your issue, use the second, optional, parameter for `hasMany` on your `User` class:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project', 'creator_id');
}
```

This should solve your problems now but, to use the relationship the other direction, you'll also need to make some changes on your `Project` model. You have two choices:

1. **Rename your relationship method:**

   ```
   public function creator()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
   ```
2. **Override the key by passing it as second parameter to `belongsTo`:**

   ```
   public function user()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'creator_id');
   }
   ```

Given what you are trying to achieve, I'd recommend you go with the first option.

Comment: Deleting this method in Project.php model doesn't even trigger error and doesn't change error message. Maybe something wrong with my relationships? Maybe its something with project method in User model?

Comment: Hmm, my bad. You're right. I've adjusted my answer.